# Change the size of coding4fun RoundButton

Tags: xaml, button, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to change the size of the coding4fun `RoundButton` I realised that the width and height properties does not work.

```
<c4f:RoundButton
ImageSource="/Assets/AppBar/play.png"
Width="150"
Height="150"/>
```

The [documentation](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RoundButton&referringTitle=Documentation) is short and has not been updated lately (`ImagePath` is now called `ImageSource`).

If it is possible to change the size of the image inside the `RoundButton` then I can work with that as well. How do? Maybe creating my own round button is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ButtonHeight and ButtonWidth properties

```
<c4f:RoundButton ButtonWidth="300" ButtonHeight="300" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, so simple. The image isn't affected by the change of the size, but `Stretch="Fill"` fixed that for me.